# Xamarin PCL compile issues

Tags: class, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, libraries, portability

I am getting XAML compiler error in my PCL project

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Core.dll 
>   Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>  
>   error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or
>   imported

Could you please help me or tell me any workaround for this.
Am using **VS 2017** Enterprise edition and doing **Xamarin** **Mac**.

Comment: A little confused by this question.  You can not do Xamarin.Mac development in Visual Studio for windows .  Ultimately the error sounds like the pcl profile is not working the way you expect in windows.   Could you use a .net Standard library instead?

Comment: Try to reload the project.